# AIX 5.3 Package Dependency

Tags: aix

I want to install gettext but i cannot because my AIX says that gettext is dependent on glib and when i try to install glib it says that I cannot because glib is in turn dependent on gettext.

Please let me know how I could get past this situation?

```
root [rover]% rpm -i gettext-0.17-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

error: failed dependencies:
        libglib-2.0.a(libglib-2.0.so.0) is needed by gettext-0.17-1

libxlsmp.a(smprt.o) is needed by gettext-0.17-1

root [rover]% rpm -i glib2-2.22.5-2.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

error: failed dependencies:
        gettext is needed by glib2-2.22.5-2
```

Regards,

Anurag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to install them both together (along with everything else it's going to insist is required:

```
rpm -i gettext-0.17-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm glib2-2.22.5-2.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `libxlsmp.a(smprt.o) is needed by gettext-0.17-1`, as it does not come from an open source RPM package, but instead from IBM.

The Page [www.perlz.org/aix](http://www.perzl.org/aix/) says it's okay to install with the `--nodeps` RPM flag.
(Then supply all needed packages at once, or start with gettext (--nodeps) and the rest should be easy).

Note: I'm not saying that using `--nodeps` is a good idea. Only that it will get you past the RPM dependency issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this as I was building git on my aix server and this will hopefully help anyone else who finds this and wants to know the exact fileset the delivers the libxlsmp.a archive library.

The fileset that you will need to install off of the base media is:

xlsmp.aix53.rte

You can run the following commands on a system that has the fileset installed or after you install it.

test123:/> lslpp -w /usr/lib/libxlsmp.a <- Since it didn't error out it must be a symlink and the -w option will need to be ran against the path that the link points to.

test123:/> ls -l /usr/lib/libxlsmp.a
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     system           31 Jan 19 17:49 /usr/lib/libxlsmp.a -> /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmp.a

test123:/> lslpp -w /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmp.a
  File                                        Fileset               Type

---

/usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmp.a             xlsmp.aix53.rte       File
So the archive library is included in the above fileset xlsmp.aix53.rte.

test123:/> lslpp -f  xlsmp.aix53.rte 
  Fileset               File

---

Path: /usr/lib/objrepos
  xlsmp.aix53.rte 3.1.0.6
                        /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmpdebug.a
                        /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmp.a
                        /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlomp_ser.a
                        /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53
                        /usr/lpp/xlsmp
The -f flag to the lslpp command list all of the files that the fileset installs.

Hope this helps someone in the future if they want to get the fileset installed that will get rid of the error.